# Looping for json object not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

I am having `json` values in an object called `dataResponse`. What I want is, I want to loop the object and fill values to the control. SO for looping I tried like this below

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataResponse.Table.length; i++) {
                if (dataResponse.Table[i] != "" || dataResponse.Table[i] != null) {
                    $("#spnLinkId").text(dataResponse.Table[i].LINK_ID);
                    $("#spnSpanLength").text(dataResponse.Table[i].NE_SPAN_LENGTH);
                    $("#txtFiberActlength").val(dataResponse.Table[i].HOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH);
                    $("#txtLITActlength").val(dataResponse.Table[i].LIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH);

                    var hotoOfferedDate = new Date(dataResponse.Table[i].HOTO_OFFERED_DATE);
                    var FinalHotoOfferedDate = hotoOfferedDate.getDate() + '/' + (hotoOfferedDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + hotoOfferedDate.getFullYear();
                    $("#spnHotoOfferDt").text(FinalHotoOfferedDate);
                    $('#spnApprRejRemarks').text(dataResponse.Table[i].APPROV_REJECT_REMARK);


                }
                if (dataResponse.Table[i].ISABDMISSING != "" || dataResponse.Table[i].ISABDMISSING != null) {
                    if (dataResponse.Table[i].ISABDMISSING == 1) {
                        $("#FEmissingAsBuiltYes").prop("checked", true);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#FEmissingAsBuiltNo").prop("checked", true);
                    }
                }
            }
```

But I have 4 tables in an object. So for other tables it is not working as expected.

Below is my screenshot for your reference.

[image: IMG 1]

Also see

[image: IMG 2]

And my response code is below

`var dataResponse = JSON.parse(response);`

Please suggest how to loop

**[JSON DATA](https://jsfiddle.net/z44oyjf5/1/)**

Comment: Is there an error here?

Comment: @JoeFrambach: Nope, but how should I loop if i have multiple records in second table or any table if it has multiple records

Comment: In pictures I can see TableX and in code I see Table[x] being used. Try dataResponse["Table" + i]

Comment: @DanteTheSmith: yes but Table[x] still works and i dont know how to loop for child records if any

Comment: Please Improve the code so that one can understand

Comment: @JuanTheron: will it work for all the tables and also for multiple records in second or third table ?

Comment: @JuanTheron: it is looping for first table only. `data.Table.length` ...!

Comment: Sorry, my browser bugged out, let me repost:

 
If I understand you correctly, you could use: 
for (var i = 0; i < data.Table.length; i++ ) { for (var j = 0; j < data.Table[i].length; j++) { } }

In the future, try phrasing your question a bit more spesific.

Comment: @JuanTheron: do u have any query related to my question ? i dont think so your answer is perfect. see my json data link for the data. you will get an idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use this coding format to iterate over all tables,

```
for (var key in response)
{  
   console.log(key); //key will give Table, Table1 etc.  
   for(var i = 0; i < response[key].length; i++) 
     {
        var data = response[key][i]; // data will give object in table based on key
        if (data.ISABDMISSING != null) 
           {
              if (data.ISABDMISSING == 1) 
                 {
                     console.log(data.ISABDMISSING);
                 }
           }    
      }
}
```